# What would be better way to open external URL with Affiliate Links?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, url-launcher

I want to offer some products/services on my Flutter app through affiliate links (https://www.amazon.com/REF######).

What would be a better way to lunch this URL and improve the chances of getting the refer from the link? I've some options below, but let me know if I could make some improvments on my code.

```
void launchAmazon() async {
const url = 'https://www.amazon.com/REF######';
if (await canLaunch(Uri.encodeFull(url))) {
await launch(url);
} else {
throw ‘Could not launch $url’;
}
```

Second option:

```
onPressed: () async {
                  if (await launchUrlString("${Get.arguments[4]}",
                      mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication)) {
                    await launchUrlString("${Get.arguments[4]}",
                        mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
                  } else {
                    throw 'Não foi possível carregar o endereço: "${Get.arguments[4]}"url';
                  }
                },
```

Do I need to add?

```
forceWebView: true, enableJavaScript: true
```

Besides the URL launch question, do I need to do some extra configurations on my App?

Let me know if you need something else! Thanks!!

I've tried the second option already.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to your option 1 and it's working fine. Just take note that opening links in an external app can cause your iOS apps to be rejected.

Apple desires apps to open all links in the application.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks @Parsa! I'll keep it this way. What about the "mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication" and "forceWebView: true, enableJavaScript: true"? Are you using something simmilar or this is not needed?